# How to connect Data processor, Content Views & Content View CiviCRM on a remote WP site

Tags: wordpress, data-processor

We're struggling to connect CiviCRM on server A (source) with a Data processor that we want to expose on a WP site on server B (target). We're using WP 5.7.2 and CiviCRM 5.39.

What we've done until now:

- Installed Dataprocessor on site A with CiviCRM. A processor is set up
  and ready to be remotely exposed.
- Installed CiviCRM McRestFace on site B to connect both sites. Connection is ok and we've successfully tried with a contact form 7
- Installed Content Views on site B to show the data.

Question is now: where do we install Content Views CiviCRM Data Processor?

If on source site, then we can't find the Data Processor on target site.

If on target site, then we have this error `It looks like CiviCRM is not activated, Content Views CiviCRM integration requires CiviCRM to be installed and activated.`  which is obvious because CiviCRM is on source site. And then we don't even need `CiviCRM McRestFace` because they already share the same database.

If we install `Content Views` and `Content Views CiviCRM Data Processor` on source site then we see the option 'CiviCRM' when adding a new view but why would we use `Content Views` on the source site.

We've looked after documentation and on SE but haven't found yet anything useful.

Are we missing something obvious like an other extension (I saw two of them made by Andrei Mondoc and especially [this one](https://github.com/mecachisenros/content-views-civicrm-remote)) or [is this](https://github.com/agileware/content-views-civicrm-data-processor/issues/2) still the current state that it doesn't work on remote site?

If this is not yet possible (we could also contribute), are there user cases of making it possible other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jaap from CiviCoop has released [this extension](https://github.com/CiviMRF/synchronizing-civicrm-data-to-custom-posts) to fill the gap.

Actually, we've managed to reach our goal by directly calling the API through an URL.